# jQuery mobile on Windows Phone 7 will not render... Fiddle included

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

On [this](http://jquerymobile.com/2011/03/jquery-mobile-alpha-4-released/) jQuery blogpost...

> We’re thrilled to announce WP7 is now a supported platform and has a solid A- experience...

All that renders is a blank page on winmo7... And I have what seems to be the same exact device they use on the photo.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/QfVsq/) fiddle is a simple two page layout that works fine on every browser except IE on winmo7.

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/QfVsq/

Comment: i don't know, i know i have read that jQuery mobile is supposed to work on wp7, but when i ran some tests on wp7 ie, ie bombed every test, i can check into it at work tomorrow and see if i come across anything.

Comment: Weird thing is... The demo does run fine on the device.

Comment: hmmmmm that is strange, ill upload your fiddle onto something i can view tomorrow and check into it. ill let you know if i come up with anything.

Comment: i just tried wp7 ie with some jQuery mobile demos today, and the demos run but not well, but its not jQuery mobile, its mobile IE, the browser is just plain bad, but the fiddle worked on an HTC Arrive, i didnt have too much time to mess around today, but i am going to mess around more tomorrow, hopefully you can find a fix, but i will continue to look into it.

Comment: I did get it working, but I really wouldn't call it a fix. I posted the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working switching my jquery-mobile library from http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js to http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/ which makes NO SENSE.

It seems as thought the downloadable version is different than the one they use on their demo.

I ran a file diff and confirmed that they are different.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on my device (Samsung Focus). Although it takes a while to load.

My suggestion is to make sure you have your IE settings on your phone set to "Mobile" and you'll probably want to make sure your not using too much of the phone's memory(eg Music Player), because if you do it takes a while to load.

Comment: Thanks for the response... How long did it take to load?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my instance of this by removing data-role="button" from my input submit elements... Odd that making an input element explicitly a button should act differently than implicitly doing so...